# error when run bundle exec rake db:migrate in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

when I run bundle exec rake db:migrate in windows CMD, it shows "ruby.exe is not recognized as an internal command...
but ruby.exe -v works fine..
what should I do now?

Comment: Is Ruby in your PATH? (Just a thought, not sure if it needs to be)